# LibGDX app not updating fast enough on phone

Tags: android, optimization, libgdx

I know this a common problem when developing apps: the app runs smooth on desktop, but not on the device itself. But the problem here is not the framerate, but the update time when the character jumps.

When the screen is tapped, the character is supposed to jump and then fall back down because of the gravity, but on my android device, when the character jumps, he stays airborne for way too long before touching the ground again.

Last time I had a similar problem, was when I wasn't using an AssetManager. I used to load the textures each time the specific gamestate was shown and then dispose them.

```
texture = new Texture("placeholder.png");
```

After I had programmed an AssetManager to load all of my textures and files before the app started(in a loading screen), the game started running smoothly again.

But now, the problem is back and I am not sure how to fix it this time. Is the solution similar to lag caused by framerate(creating objects in the render() method, updating too many things at once etc.)? I noticed this problem started after I implemented the shop, so should I try looking at its code?

EDIT: Here is some of my code:
The render method from the "laggy" Game State:

```
   cam.update();
    sb.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    sb.begin();
    sb.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    sb.draw(bg, cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth / 2, 0, cam.viewportWidth, cam.viewportHeight);
    for(Coin coin : coins)
        sb.draw(coin.getCoin(), coin.getPosCoin().x + 300, coin.getPosCoin().y, 100, 100);

    sb.draw(bird.getTexture(), bird.getPosition().x, bird.getPosition().y, bird.getBounds().getWidth(), bird.getBounds().getHeight());

    for (Tube tube : tubes) {
            sb.draw(tube.getTopTube(), tube.getPosTopTube().x + 300, tube.getPosTopTube().y, 230, 1660);
            sb.draw(tube.getBottomTube(), tube.getPosBotTube().x + 300, tube.getPosBotTube().y, 230, 1660);}
    sb.draw(grass, groundPos1.x, groundPos1.y);
    sb.draw(grass, groundPos2.x, groundPos2.y);
    sb.draw(grass, groundPos3.x, groundPos3.y);
    font120.draw(sb, score + "", cam.position.x - 29, cam.viewportHeight - 105, 100, Align.center, false);
    if(gameState == 1) {
        sb.draw(pausemenu, cam.position.x - 315, cam.viewportHeight / 2 - 625 / 2, 625, 625);
        table.setPosition(cam.position.x, 560);
    }
    if(gameState == 2){
        String highScore = getHighScore() + "";
        String coins = getCoins() + "";
        sb.draw(gameover, cam.position.x - gameover.getWidth() / 2 - 85 , cam.viewportHeight / 2 - gameover.getHeight() / 2, 600, 500);
        highScoreFont.draw(sb, "Highscore: " + highScore, cam.position.x - highScoreFont.getScaleX() / 2 - 250 , cam.viewportHeight - 425, 500, Align.center, true);
        coinsFont.draw(sb, coins, cam.position.x - 201, cam.viewportHeight - 590, 500, Align.center, false);
        sb.draw(coin, cam.position.x - layout.width / 2 - 51, cam.viewportHeight - 660, 90, 90);
        restartButton.setPosition(cam.position.x - restartButton.getWidth() / 2, 525);
   }

    if (gameState != 1)
        pauseButton.setPosition(cam.position.x - 300, 1150);

    sb.end();
    stage.act();
    stage.draw();
}
```

The jump physics:

```
    if (position.y > 0 && isAlive) {
        velocity.add(0, GRAVITY);
    }
    velocity.scl(dt);
    if(isAlive) {
        position.add(MOVEMENT * dt, velocity.y);
        velocity.scl(1 / dt);
    }
```

Comment: Rule of thumb, the `new` keyword should not appear anywhere in your `render` loop.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I know, I have made sure that it does not appear. Anything else I can do?

Comment: Could be a hundred different things. The LibGDX forums would be a better place to get help with this because you can post a bunch of code and there is room to have a discussion about it.

Comment: Show us the jumping code. If you want to achieve similar gameplay at different framerates you need to divide velocity by the delta time (time since last frame). This way for each frame rate the game mechanics will be the same.

Comment: If you want help with your code we need to see more than just a single line. We cannot read you mind and guess what you are doing.

Comment: @Madmenyo I am already using Delta Time. Everything used to work the same, both on the pc and the phone, before I added the shop. I tried removing the shop to see if it is the one causing the problem, but it's not. I'll try sharing some code with you.

Comment: Added some code in the post

Comment: Why are you scaling up with deltatime: `velocity.scl(1 / dt)`?

Comment: @Madmenyo Because otherwise it won't work?

Comment: `scl(1/0.016)` for 60 fps would scale up your velocity by 60 for each frame. So if velocity is 1 you would be at 3600 in 1 second. `scl(1/0.033)` for 30 fps would scale up velocity by 30 each frame so in 1 second you would only reach 900. This is surely not framerate independent.

Comment: For better reading, do all your velocity calculations first. Then scale it by delta time and then add it to a position vector.

Comment: @Madmenyo, if you know so much about frame dependencies, why don't you simply correct my code? Your indications are not much help.

Comment: @vladutelu Because we are here to help you learn something, not do your work for you. It just does not make sense to first divide with the delta and then turn it back again by multiplying (1 / delta). You say you are scaling up with delta time otherwise "it won't work". What exactly won't work. Be clear and constructive please and don't ask others to complete or correct your code, EVER. If you show enough effort there are plenty of people out there that will help you out.